# Add background color between header and footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I am trying to add a background color to the area between the bottom of the header to the top of the footer. But, somehow the whole page gets filled with the background color. Can someone explain it and tell how to do it?

I think the problem is the *Background* package but I don't know how to solve it or it there are any better solutions to add the custom background fill to every page.

**Minimal working sample**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

% Background formatting
\backgroundsetup{%
    color=blue,
    angle=0,
    contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            % Add background
            \fill[color = black!10] (current page header area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.south east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example?

Comment: `\fill[color = black!10] (current page header area.south west) rectangle (current page footer area.north east);`  works for me.

Comment: @nidhin I will try, just a sec.

Comment: @nidhin, did you load any library? I got `Package pgf Error: No shape named current page header area is known. ...k!10] (current page header area.south west)`

Comment: @Sigur `tikzpagenodes`

Comment: @nidhin I have added a working sample now :)

Comment: @nidhin, so, it is a package, not a tikz library, right?

Comment: @Sigur its a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works, but not with the `background` package (as you suspect). `eso-pic` also allows you to fill all pages, but does not have the problems `background` has.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Background formatting
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            % Add background
            \fill[color = black!10] (current page header area.south west) 
            rectangle (current page text area.south east);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\clearpage
\section{Summary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the margins, you can shift the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \fill[color = black!10] ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-2cm,yshift=\headsep]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=2cm]current page.south east);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I guess it might be be cause of the background package I am using to apply the color fill to all pages (but the title page).